# Remove the space between number and % in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I use the `siunitx` package for unit management. However, i want to remove the space between the number and the percent symbol, i.e. 1% instead of 1 %. Can i redefine the `\percent` command to achieve this for my complete document so that i do not have to do this by hand and write `1\%`.

I have tens of numbers where I'm typing `\SI{1}{\percent}` and i want to change all these numbers with a single redefinition of "`\percent`"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to redeclare the unit

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}
\begin{document}
\qty{1}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why is the \char` necessary?