# Re-declaring \bit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

It is possible to re-declare/redefine existing siunitx units in [general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351204/23277). However, this seems to fail for the binary units `\bit` (and `\byte`) as shown in the MWE below.

Only if the declaration is done after the preamble via `\AtBeginDocument` the declaration works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  binary-units,
]{siunitx}

% \AtBeginDocument{
\DeclareSIUnit\bit{b}
% }

\begin{document}

\SI{8}{\bit}

\end{document}
```

Why is this the case? Is this a bug? Why is `\bit` defined as `bit` in the first place while `\byte` is simply `B`? This produces rather unreadable output with IEC prefixes like *Gibit*.

I am using version 2.7a (2017-01-01) from TexLive 2016.

Comment: The change only works in `\AtBeginDocument` because `siunitx` itself only loads `siunitx-binary.cfg` `\AtBeginDocument`. If you declare the unit before your declaration is overwritten. Why `\bit` is `bit` is another story...

Comment: To answer my own question regarding the `bit` bit: that's the official IEC/ISO unit *symbol* (while `b` was/is promoted by IEEE). @PhelypeOleinik, if you make your explanation a true answer (and maybe include your opinion on bug-worthyness and/or how siunitx could unify the behavior) I'd very much accept it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time of loading is certainly intentional. The `binary-units` option code (for true) is:

```latex
binary-units / true .code:n = { \AtBeginDocument { \__siunitx_load_binary: } },
```

which as the code suggests, does basically `\AtBeginDocument{\input{siunitx-binary.cfg}}` (with a little more work to have the file be loaded as a package).

It isn't clear why this is loaded `\AtBeginDocument` and not at the time of loading `siunitx` (I didn't find any hint in the source, at least). But there's this:

```latex
\changes{v2.5m}{2012/11/27}{Modified loading of \opt{binary-units}}
```

but it doesn't say *what* changed...
Only Joseph knows :-)

---

As for the representation of `\bit`, the [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/), which is used as reference for `siunitx`, doesn't say anything about digital storage units, so it's probably down to what you said:

> That [`bit`] is the official IEC/ISO unit *symbol* (while `b` was/is promoted by IEEE)

so it's basically a matter of choice between the two. Although I think that in written text `8 bit` is clearer than `8 b`, the former becomes weird when combined with prefixes/other units, so it's a tough pick...

Comment: Should it be `8 bits`, though? The question of the plural `s` is usually irrelevant because of abbreviations. `8 bit` feels odd to me.